# What should a user do if they feel oppressed by the majority?

Tags: discussion, abuse

What should a lone user do if they feel tyrannised by a majority of users and moderators on some particular SE site?

For example, suppose this lone user doubts the reasons for closure and feels that their questions are being closed simply because it was that person who had submitted them, what should they do?

To raise the concern on that particular SE site’s Meta would likely produce only an unhelpful, partisan response from that same majority of users and moderators I initially referred to.

---

#### Footnote

I apologise if this question depresses anyone; I appreciate and recognise the charitable and generous, and wish only to help those charitable and generous persons contribute more to the new users’ benefit.

Comment: this happens also to established users - when it happened to me, I deleted and walked away from the site, despite the subject matter being a passion of mine.

Comment: @SabreTooth I'm very sorry to hear that (that hostility obstructed your interest), but thanks for sharing.

Comment: I still have a passion for the subject, and thankfully I am a member of a group of very welcoming sites!

Comment: @SabreTooth Heartening to hear! Could I ask if you would please share which sites are more welcoming? But please don't, if this is forbidden on SE. I personally only know about Reddit.

Comment: Oh, I mean SE sites - some SE sites are very welcoming! I happily contribute to these

Comment: @SabreTooth Ah I see. I misunderstood you; I thought that you resorted to other sites for the same subjects.

Comment: No problems, you do make a very good point though  -to raise issues on particular site's meta or chat would draw a negative, and even hostile response.  My experience was that not only my post (on topic and upvoted) ridiculed, my research and my person were also attacked.  I flagged and nothing happened - so I walked away - for *that* subject, I go elsewhere.

Comment: The site in question for me is [History SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/20918/8309) but maybe the problem lies with my naivety with the subject. Anyhow, would you mind if I asked where you go, for *that* subject of yours?

Comment: I now head onto scientific sites and research gate for that topic

Comment: Your apology is useless, they don't understand the concept of forgiveness. And actually, they should apologize to you, which they won't ever do.

Answer (score 30):

The first step would be to at least *try* to raise the issue on meta. If he/she never speaks up, others may never realize there's a problem. He/she should focus on the merits of the question rather than make a case for personal discrimination right out of the gate.

If all else fails, he/she can always reach the community team by using the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page for an impartial review.

If even *that* fails and no resolution/consensus can be found, there is the unfortunate possibility that the site and the person simply don't see eye to eye. I've seen it go both ways - sometimes the community changes their ways, sometimes the person realizes it's time to move on.

Comment: Adding to this, in my own experience, at least, the majority of this community tends to be good about focusing more on individual posts than the user that posted them, especially if that person calmly and constructively raises discussion about it. That said, it's also important to remember that just because a user and a community may not see eye-to-eye doesn't make that user a "bad person" - i.e. if you start feeling overly defensive (definitely doesn't look like the case here, but often these types of issues go that way), be wary and take time to cool down, as you don't need to feel that way.

Comment: Precisely what I did, Anna - I moved on from a site in particular where I did not fit their stereotype.  Now I am happily participating in more accepting sites.

Answer (score 24):

Please start by ensuring your questions follow the rules of the site you are posting on.

Read the How to Ask pages, familiarise yourself with the stack's culture or customs. This process is a lot harder than it should be when the help pages are not very clear or up to date. However, in my experience (on History.SE at least) downvotes and close votes are normally accompanied by comments explaining what was wrong.

It is understandable that you may instinctively reject or ignore negative comments, but that is not a constructive way of approaching the problem. Many, if not most, people vote and comment in good faith. It behooves you to consider their advice and opinions fairly. *Especially* when you find your questions repeatedly subject to closures.

---

In this case, your question is obviously motivated by your experience over at [History](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2101/why-are-my-questions-downvoted-and-closed). I can understand why you are upset with the poor receptions you have been getting this month. But you should recognise that - in the eyes of many at H.SE - your questions have not been following the stack's rules.

When you first started posting at History, you received multiple helpful comments pointing out why your questions do not fit our guidelines. To name an example, your question [*On average, are British and Canadians more moral than Americans?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16907/compare-racism-across-canada-vs-british-empire-vs-us) received three comments pointing out that:

[image]

When you took the [issue to meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/how-to-improve-what-does-history-prove-about-social-issues-for-british-vs-can), you received further feedback and suggestions. In the end however all you did was to *edit the title*. That really didn't fix anything. Unsurprisingly, the community did not vote to reopen.

This is not an isolated case. Your questions are usually [opinion based](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19288/was-the-uss-pre-emptive-bombardment-of-iwo-jima-insufficient) and typically [confusing](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20802/in-ww2-why-were-some-north-americans-elites-anglophobic) or [too broad](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/how-often-and-for-what-reasons-were-soldiers-of-higher-rank-shot-by-those-of-low). These are all close reason on H.SE. Additionally, I suggest trying to frame your questions in a more neutral way. Loading posts with [appeals to emotions](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19288/was-the-uss-pre-emptive-bombardment-of-iwo-jima-insufficient) or [incredulity](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20917/what-did-even-the-nazis-consider-as-wicked) tends to raise red flags for at least some of us.

Comment: Thank you for your answer here. I'll think more about that question, but could I please ask if you read http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/2101/8309 : i wrote 'Could I please request some help with editing my questions to improve them?' I did read the 'further feedback and suggestions', but possibly due to my lack of professional training, many of them were unclear to me. For example, I asked for clarification [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-was-a-ww2-german-field-marshal-abandoned-in-the-ussr#comment51881_20803) but see no responses.

Comment: Anyhow, should I be replying to you here or on History? I do NOT want to restrict my OP above to my case only; I intended it to apply to all.

Comment: You didn't ask for "clarification", you asked *"what ought to be asked"*. You're the one who posted the question, you should know what you yourself are asking.

Comment: I wrote "what ought to be asked" to clarify what question user Mark C Wallace was thinking of, because he wrote: 'What's the real question?'; I did intend this as clarification. I confirm that I know what I was asking, but I don't understand what this user meant..

Comment: You also wrote `you may instinctively reject or ignore negative comments`, but I confirm that I did read the comments. I then responded to them, such as those here: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20802/in-ww2-why-were-some-north-americans-elites-anglophobic#comment51935_20802 and http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/how-often-and-for-what-reasons-were-soldiers-of-higher-rank-shot-by-those-of-low#comment51936_20896. About `all you did was to edit the title`, I'm earnestly trying to do more and would be grateful for replies to my comments there.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit  That's a totally different question than the one you linked earlier. In this case, you **also** asked *"why did he like singularly Field Marshal William Slim?"* and hence it is unclear what on earth you are really asking. This was communicated to you at the time by both me and MarkCWallace's comments. My patience is wearing extremely thin at this point, please take a minute to really think things through before posting.

Comment: I'll be happy to answer, but to clarify, were two previous comments related to this question, removed (they were posted within the past 2 hours or so)? I believe that an earlier comment of yours started with: '`You literally make no sense whatsoever'.` But I can't remember the rest of that comment?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Yes, it appears to have been removed. We seemed to have been graced by mod presence just now.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. Ah I see; I'll just disregard the removed post then. My question is: 'In WW2, why were some North Americans elites Anglophobic?' If *"why did he like singularly Field Marshal William Slim?"* confuses, I can happily remove it. Does this help? Please advise how else I can improve that question?

Comment: Yes, that helps. In general *all* of your questions could do with less tangentialising prattle. But the fact remains that this particular question is, as Mark noted, "not just trivial but tautological". By then North America already had a huge population. Of course "some" of them would be Anglophobic. To be a meaningful question, you need to at the bare minimum demonstrate that these Americans demonstrate an unusual amount of Anglophobia - which would require sorely missed preliminary research.